# Get data from json body in couchdb

Tags: json, couchdb

I have the following body .

```
{

  "sEcho: : 2, 

  creteria : ['everything' | 'roomcode' | 'roomfunction'], 

  textBox : "key1, key2, key3,..",

  dt : '03/04/2014',

  "iDisplayStart" : '0'

  iDisplayLength : [10| 25| 50|100]  

  iSortCol_0 : ''last_modified' ,

  "sSortDir_0":"asc"

}
```

How can I get these values into my list using request ( should not pass through url as query param). Is it possible by?

```
var sEcho=req.form.sEcho;
```

Comment: In what framework are you programming? In which context is the "var sEcho=req.form.sEcho;"?

Comment: Ok, but you don't give any information about your programming language, framework used to process requests, etc... so it's not possible to give any answer.

Comment: For your answer, you are really using javascript! And this question is not about couchdb...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the code is to be like,

var active_text = JSON.parse( req.body );

var field =active_text.sEcho;